# Prisma, My SQL, number of allocations is different for transaction

Tags: mysql, prisma

```
     await prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
        const user = await tx.user.create({
            data: {
                ...
            },
        })

        await tx.account.create({
            data: {
                ...
            },
        });`
```

There is an account table and a user table.

Both are set to auto increment id. Primary is

This app is in service. Numbers 795 to 800, 803, and 810 are stored in the user table. (I don't know why the number is blank in the middle, but maybe it didn't fail during transaction processing?)

Anyway, the problem is that the account is not empty in the same amount. Obviously, if the numbers from 795 to 800 are not in the user table, there should be 5 empty spaces in the account as well, but the accounts are almost always stored sequentially. Is there any way to prevent this?

I want both to have as little empty space as possible.

Comment: Instead of auto increment, can you use uuids to prevent this situation from happening?

Comment: @NurulSundarani Yah that may solve this problem. but I want it to be number

Comment: Ah Okay, MySQL's auto_increment feature does not guarantee a strict sequence without gaps. Gaps can occur due to rollbacks, DELETE statements, or server crashes. However, by default, MySQL should not skip numbers when auto_increment is used under normal conditions.

If you want to ensure that there are no gaps in the auto_increment sequence, you can use a custom implementation for generating unique IDs.

Comment: @NurulSundarani Okay appreciate it